# Data locality problems when consuming with multiple topics from Kafka with Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

We are using Spark streaming to consumer records from Kafka.
We have 13 nodes with 12 cores on each node.

When we configure 1 topic with 24 partitions to be consumed, we configure 24 executors and 1 core per executor on our Spark consumer. In this case no problem, each executor is assigned to process a topic/partition and it keeps consistent from one batch to another (task locality levels are PROCESS_LOCAL).

When we configure 2 topics (first one with 19 partitions and the second one with 5 partitions for example) we have performance problems because topic/partition processing is not consistent. Some topic/partition are assigned to be processed on the same executor than another one and this can cause data locality problems (task locality level is RACK_LOCAL).

How can we have consistent processing of the topic/partitions on all executors?

Changing the configuration of our Spark consumer to 12 executors with 2 cores on each executor does not solve the issue because in this case 3 tasks can be assigned to the same executors. 
And the issue is still present with 8 executors with 3 cores, 6 executors with 4 cores and 4 executors with 6 cores.

I have tested 1 topic with 40 partitions and still no data locality problem, mono topic processing is much more stable.

Spark 2.1
Kafka 0.10.1
LocationStrategy = preferConsistent

Comment: I would suggest looking into using Structured Streaming, which caches the `TopicPartition` on each selected executor, especially if you're developing a new application on Spark now, using Structured Streaming is the future.

Comment: Thank you for your help! We are using Spark 2.1 and Structured Streaming is alpha, it could be a good alternative only with a more stable release of Structured Streaming. Moreover we are in production deployment so it will be better if we can resolve this issue using Spark Streaming.

Comment: The latest version is 2.2, and I wouldn't call it alpha. We're running with it in production already, aggregating over 10TB of data a day.

Comment: I mean Structured Streaming embedded with Spark 2.1 is alpha, not with Spark 2.2 but we can't go to Spark 2.2 now.

Comment: I would highly recommend it instead of fighting Spark Streaming. It might save you time.